# Do I need to secure my messages with checksum when using TCP?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, tcp

Using TCP as the network protocol, I prefix the size (and potentially checksum?) of each message before sending the message through the wire. I'd like to know, does it make sense to calculate and transmit the checksum of the message, to ensure that the message will be delivered (if and when it will be delivered) unchanged, e.g. because of some network error. Currently I'm sending 4-byte size + 2-byte checksum (CRC-16) of the message, before sending the message itself. The other endpoint correctly identifies expected message length, reads it, and validates the checksum.

I know that TCP has internal packet validation mechanism, and I have a strong feeling that my message validation at application level is redundant, but I'm not sure and need your advice before I make a decision.

I'm in the process of developing the client-server application, with tens of thousands potential connections to the server daily. Even a single damaged byte in any of the messages might cause whole chain of incorrect messages exchanged, which is unacceptable (well, almost all client-server applications have the same requirements, don't they). So I want to be sure - can I safely trust TCP's internal reliability, or is it better to provide my own checksum validation mechanism. And I'm talking about small, two byte checksums (CRC-16), I'm not talking about digitally signing messages, etc. (And the system is developed in .Net (C#) using sockets, if that makes any difference).

Comment: How about simply sending everything over SSL? That way you get security and protection against accidental changes at the same time.

Comment: Why not use WCF and stop worrying about low-level protocol details.

Comment: Sometimes WCF is not an option, and when it is - it usually is a preferred approach. But this time I'm interested in sockets solution.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this paper](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Paper/22436.aspx) "the checksum will fail to detect errors for roughly 1 in 16 million to 10 billion packets". Assuming a packet size of 1024 bytes, this amounts to one undetected error every 16 GB to 10 TB of network traffic.

Many protocols like HTTP, FTP, SMTP and probably many more rely on the checksums in the underlying layers. It is my belief that this practice is **questionable** given the above numbers.

Sidenote: The same is true for hard drives as well. Typical desktop drives have an error detection capability of 1 bit in 10 TB read. Read your 2 TB disk 5 times and on average you will suffer one incident of corruption.

To answer your question: if your **tolerance** for very rare, spurious failures is medium to high, don't bother checksumming. If you can't tolerate any corruption, add a checksum to your protocol.

Comment: The MD5 vs. SHA1 part is a bit misleading. Chances of MD5 not finding an accidental error are the same as those for truncated SHA1. For deliberate collisions, no 128 bit hash can be considered secure and SHA1 has severe weaknesses as well. (if you have an attacker, the much trickier question of exchanging the hash arises, so it's not even a simple "choose a strong hash")

Comment: SHA1 is practically collision resistant against an attacker while MD5 has ceased to be. Also 128 bits are indeed enough for practical security (a 2nd preimage attack still has 2^128 operations complexity). On the other hand that part of the answer was not essential and to short to be useful. Removed.

Comment: A brute-force collision against a 128 bit hash has cost 2^64, which a powerful attacker can achieve. 128 bit hashes can offer acceptable pre-image resistance, but not collision resistance. For SHA1 there are faster than brute-force collision attacks but nobody bothered to implement them. I would not feel comfortable using SHA1 in any situation where MD5 is already broken.

Answer (score 1):

As far as TCP is concerned, like others have pointed out, it is not 100% reliable and some messages can get corrupt during transmission.

To keep integrity of messages you will have to use CRC at the application level.

However, if you are using SSL/TLS then you do not have to do CRC at the application level as it is already done. Messages exchanged over SSL/TLS are checked for integrity by the libraries. Almost all of the algorithms in SSL/TLS cipher suite perform message authentication. To know which algorithms does HMAC or doesn't or have more reliable one you have to see its name. The algorithm names have three parts. For example,

```
  "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" has following three parts;

  TSL_RSA     => Asymmetric algorithm for key exchange during initial handshake.
  AES_256_GCM => Symmetric algorithm for message encryption.
  SHA384      => HMAC for message integrity.
```

So in the above SSL/TLS algorithm the SHA384 is used for message authentication and that is why you do not have to do CRC in your application.

Answer (score 0):

TCP does not guarantee 100% that your data will be transferred and received the way it was sent.

It is always a chance that your message **3_ABC** with CRC **42** will accidentally be converted to **10_FU@0Ээ^+Ъr** with the same CRC. However, you *still should* rely on it.

Since the TCP, as you have already found out, simply sends the checksum of each packet and compares it to the content on the other side, you do not to have to do it on your own. TCP also guarantees that data comes in the order it was sent, so if you stick to the pattern  `[from 4 to 8 bytes of message's length + message itself]` that should be enough.

However, in the case you are using the message pattern, you might go into using the UDP instead. There are some ways to achive maximum network potentian exactly with UDP, not TCP. One of them is [**Lidgren.Network**](https://github.com/lidgren/lidgren-network-gen3) C# library which can send packets in multiple kinds of reliability and order.